# Algorithm to find the nearest coordinate to a given point in a 2-D graph

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

**Problem:** 
There is a set of fixed blue coordinates. I want to find the nearest `blue` coordinate to a given `red` coordinate
[Here is the graph](http://i57.tinypic.com/21dpk6s.jpg)

**This was my approach:**

getting the cartesian distance to all the blue points and finding the minimum of it.

```
float min=Float.MAX_VALUE;
float temp=0;
for(int i=0;i<cordinateList.size;i++){
    temp=cordinateList.get(i).x*cordinateList.get(i).x+cordinateList.get(i).y*cordinateList.get(i).y;
    if(temp<min){
        min=temp;
    }
}
```

**What I need:**

My approach is not feasible because the cordinateList is very large, so finding the distance to all is very inefficient and my program fails to do the task in the given time.

**So are there any efficient algorithms than mine and any suggestions ?**

**UPDATE:**
Red points come one at a time for about million times. The blue points list is fixed. So I think I can afford any initial changes to blue points list like sorting if need.

Thank you.

Comment: you may prepare Voronoi diagram over all points, and then check which region the inspected point falls to

Comment: If the coordinates are only available in the list, and any coordinate can appear at any point in the list, there's no substantial improvement to be made since you always have to look at each point in the list, whether to calculate the distance, to sort the list, etc.  If there is some pattern to the coordinate points, though, you might be able to exploit that.  Is there?

Comment: Is the coordinate list ordered in any way? For example, sorted by the x-axis value?

Comment: @jaket - I don't think it helps ...

Comment: @StephenC - I was thinking about a variation of the closest pairs algorithm using the divide and conquer approach http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairDQ.html. The first requirement of the algorithm is to sort the points by the x axis.

Comment: And I really don't know where I was going with the idea, but I do know that the closest pair can be solved in O(n log n) time so I would assume this problem would be similar.

Comment: @WarrenDew The points refer to like a cured line(not exactly). Like a map of a river

Comment: @jaket no. But I can sort if need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply have (just) a list of points, and you need to do this once, then there is no more efficient way.

But if you have to do this procedure lots of times for lots of different points, then there are ways to improve the efficiency.  For example:

- create and use a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) data structure, or
- create and use a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram).

But note that these approaches involve set-up overheads that need to be amortized over a number of lookups (i.e. find-the-nearest-point calculations) before you break even.

Comment: Thank you.I could heard that in Google map API I can map to the nearest marker. So I think that if there is such efficient algorithm I can use it for mine

Comment: I think [kd-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) might be the best fit for this particular problem.

Comment: @MikePedersen Thank you. Will refer

Comment: @MikePedersen Thank you. looks very interesting. Have you worked with it ? :)

Comment: Make a kd-tree out of the blue points, then just find the nearest neighbor using the kd-tree for each red point. Though, I take it that the number of blue points is much smaller than the number of red points, in which case that's about as good as you can get. If the opposite is true, then a combination of quad-trees and kd-trees might be better.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is a hierarchical tree, I.e. dendogram or hierarchical cluster. You can use the clusterfck JS library.